# NoReverseMatch Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-views, django-templates

Estoy intentando presentar los seguidores de un usuario al dar click en "followers" que se encuentra en mi plantilla detail.html, pero recibo una excepcion: Reverse for 'followers' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P[^/]+)/followers/$']

**parte de mi detail.html # detalle del usuario**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <b>{{ followers }}</b> <a href="{% url 'users:followers' username %}">followers</a>
</div>
```

**parte de mi urls.py**

```
path(
    route="profile/<str:username>/",
    view=views.UserDetailView.as_view(),
    name="detail"
),

path(
    route="profile/<str:username>/followers/",
    view=views.ListFollowersView.as_view(),
    name="followers"
),
```

**parte de mi vista. Esta vista lista los followers de un usuario**

```
class ListFollowersView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
"""Return all followers"""

template_name = "users/followers.html"
context_object_name = "followers"

def get_queryset(self):
    self.user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs["username"])
    follows = Follow.objects.filter(following=self.user.pk)
    followers_id = [follow.follower for follow in follows]
    followers = User.objects.filter(user__id__in=followers_id)
    return followers
```

**followers.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head_content %}
<title>@{{ user.username }} | Platzigram</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block container %}
<div class="container">
    {% for follower in followers %}
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 mt-5 p-0 post-container">
            <div class="media mb-3">
                {% if follower.profile.picture %}
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2 rounded-circle" width="40px" height="40px" src="/media/{{ follower.profile.picture }}" alt="">
                {% else %}
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                {% endif %}

                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">{{follower.username}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Otro problema es que después de intentar implementar esta funcionalidad. cuando quiero ir al detalle del usuario me devuelve el mismo error y esto antes no pasaba. por qué será esto?

Agradezco a quien pueda ayudar a este novato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui: *Reverse for 'followers' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P[^/]+)/followers/$']* te esta diciendo que no se estan pasando  argumentos, por eso pone esto  '('',)', en este caso no esta pasando el username.

Entonces primero cersiorate que aqui:

```
<b>{{ followers }}</b> <a href="{% url 'users:followers' username %}">followers</a>
```

Si exista username, en tu template pon {{username}} y ve que si se este pasando correctamente.

Con respecto al detalle de usuario comparte la view completa para ver por que sucede el error, probablemente no esta leyendo bien el kwarg de la url.